# Finding and editing string in file

Tags: c++, string, file, sorting

I'm writing a C++ program to optimize a pseudopotential. This requires me to edit the same file multiple times and change some parameters. The file in question looks like this

```
   pg      Nitrogen
        tm2      2.0
 n=N  c=car
       0.0       0.0       0.0       0.0       0.0       0.0
    1    4
    2    0      2.00      0.00
    2    1      3.00      0.00
    3    2      0.00      0.00
    4    3      0.00      0.00
      1.15     1.15      1.15      1.15      0.15      0.15
```

What I want to edit is the last line. I want to be able to change the number and use bisection to optimize my pseudo. I already have the bisection algorithm ready, the problem I'm having is that if I use for example `String.find(1.15)` it doesn't give me control over which one of them is changing and I haven't been able to write the code that edits the file. The program that uses that file is very sensitive to spaces and those are not tabs.

If someone can help me to think on a function that receives a number and edits, for example, the 3rd one I would be very grateful. Then I'll build on that to finish my code.

**Edit**

After reading the comments on how awful the file format is I started trying to see if it would work making the format nicer and actually I found out that the first space of the first line can be eliminated and the numbers can be separated by commas. Even if the manual says other ways. So, the last line can look like this:

```
1.15,1.15,1.15,1.15,0.15,0.15
```

Comment: Haul this into Excel, make your changes, then save as CSV format.  No need to write a program.  You may also want to research creating macros in Excel.

Comment: ...or if you're set on writing a program, separate the concerns: read the file into some "model" or data structure. Do your work on the data and then write out a new file.

Comment: The thing is that another program receives the file, makes the calculation, and spits out the results. I have to make some calculations with those results, edit the file, run the program again until I get a good optimization of the pseudo. Really dint understand much of @John3136 answare

Comment: This file format is not friendly for the programs to pass, why not choose CSV as previous comments suggested?

Comment: I didn't create the program that does the heavy calculations. In fact, is a complicated program which I had to install previuslly. But I have to work with what I have.

Comment: Use `getline` to read the file line by line. Once you read a line, write it to a new file, except for the last line. Put it in a vector, change the values, write the values, done. White-space is a valid separator, don’t make your life harder.